# angularjs DELETE array of objects

Tags: angularjs, rest, restful-url, angularjs-resource

Please help me understand: why angularjs not delete array of objects

```
$scope.removeAll = function(
    all = _.pluck($scope.uploader.queue, 'file');

    all.length && HTTPStorage.query_delete(all,
        function () {
            $scope.uploader.clearQueue();
            delay.resolve();
        });
)
```

service:

```
services.factory('HTTPStorage', ['$resource', function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/v1/documents/storage/:id', {'id': '@id'},{
            'query_delete': {
                method: 'DELETE',
                isArray: true
            }
        });
    }]);
```

objects array:
[ {

```
file: "storage/dave-macvicar-1130x1130.jpg",  
id: 377,  
is_external: false,  
size: 272543,  
status: "unknown",  
type: "image/jpeg",  
upload_type: 1,  
uploaded: "2014-09-03" }, {...same objects, with different id}, {}]
```

angular sent to server:
/api/v1/documents/storage?0=%7B%22webkitRelativePath%22:%22%22,%22lastModifiedDate%22:%222014-08-19T14:11:17.000Z%22,%22name%22:%22Screenshot+from+2014-08-19+18:11:16.png%22,%22type%22:%22image%2Fpng%22,%22size%22:607898,%22id%22:381,%22upload_type%22:1,%22user%22:%22%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9+%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%22,%22file%22:%22storage%2F0ccf78bc333a11e48c4bb8030570fabc%2FScreenshot+from+201  ..... and more symbols

how send to server array of objects to delete those objects
if use curl all normal:

```
curl -X DELETE -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/documents/storage -d '[{"id": 330}, {"id": 333}]' -u user:pass
```

Comment: have you added the `ngResourse` module along with other modules?

Comment: yes, i did it. 
do i use right way?

Comment: DELETE is not allowing you to send data in same way as POST did.

Comment: thank very much, Kasyx.
does exist some hook(trick)?

Comment: use POST instead of DELETE :)

Comment: Well... For deleting more data I'm using POST. Easiest trick to do.

Comment: oh, sad (. 
may i can use:
curl -X DELETE -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/documents/storage?id=330&id=333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the ids for delete via queryString, pretty much like this:

```
http://localhost:3030/api/books?TENANTID=xxx&q=%5B1,3%5D
```

%5B equals to [

%5D equals to ]

so the untransformed url should be like:

```
http://localhost:3030/api/books?TENANTID=xxx&q=[1,3]
```

In you angular code, it can be write like:

```
...
.factory('BookEntity', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        '/api/books/:id',
        {id: '@id'},
        {
            create: {method: 'POST'},
            update: {method: 'PUT'}
        }
    );
}])

...
ScriptEntity.delete({q: JSON.stringify(bookIds)}) //bookIds is an array contains of Ids you want to delete
```